In the Rust Programming Language Chapter 17 why does the Post state need to be wrapped in a optio<Box...>?
The book says:
We need to set state to None temporarily rather than setting it directly with code like self.state = self.state.request_review(); to get ownership of the state value. This ensures Post can’t use the old state value after we’ve transformed it into a new state.
Mark. RustProgrammingLanguage2E (Kindle Locations 13616-13620). Kindle Edition.
But if the program is standalone how would the Post have access to the old state after the assignment?

Here's a link to the section: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html#requesting-a-review-of-the-post-changes-its-state

It's not strictly necessary. It's just to make it impossible to introduce a bug by computing the new state but accidentally leaving the post in the old state.
References:

https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/837
https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/3589

